# putting total months income into a chart in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I made a Query to get total income of each month of the year.
I'm new in vb.net and MySQL. please if anyone know a shorter Query that give the same result.

I want to put a chart where the X is for the months and Y is for the total incomes.

My Query:

```
query = "SELECT  (
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '1'
)as January,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '2'
) AS February,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '3'
)as March,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '4'
) AS April,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '5'
)as May,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '6'
) AS June,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '7'
)as July,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '8'
) AS August,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '9'
)as September,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '10'
) AS October,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '11'
)as November,
(
SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table)
FROM   bacci.income_table
where  MONTH(Date_income_table) = '12'
) AS December;"
```

The code for the chart is:

```
    Comand = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
            READER = Comand.ExecuteReader
            While READER.Read
                ChartIncomeYear.Series("Incomes").Points.AddXY(READER.GetString("Date_income_table"), READER.GetInt32("Amount_income_table"))

            End While
```

I'm using MySQL database and Visual Basic 2017.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its asking for a review. Better suited at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Codexer i didnt know about code review ill put my question in it :) thank you

Comment: Welcome, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MONTHNAME` function to directly get the name of the month and group by that.

```
SELECT SUM(amt), MONTHNAME(amt_date) 
FROM income_table
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(amt_date);
```

something like that.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62f4ba/1

for some reason fiddle link is not working, here is the entire code

```
 CREATE TABLE income_table (amt INT, amt_date DATE);

  INSERT INTO income_table
    VALUES (12500,'2017-01-01');
      INSERT INTO income_table
    VALUES (2500,'2017-01-10');

    INSERT INTO income_table
    VALUES (12500,'2017-02-01');

      INSERT INTO income_table
    VALUES (3700,'2017-02-08');

    INSERT INTO income_table
    VALUES (12500,'2017-03-01');
    INSERT INTO income_table
    VALUES (12500,'2017-04-01');
    INSERT INTO income_table
    VALUES (12500,'2017-05-01');
    INSERT INTO income_table
    VALUES (12500,'2017-06-01');
```

see in fiddle.

Comment: thank you bro the query work like a charm :)